# Why my wix created installer msi is treated as unsecurity by IE and Chrome after download?

Tags: wix

I create a MSI through Wix, it works well, however when I publish my MSI to Internet and download it from IE or Chrome, after download finished, the security scanner assumes my MIS is not a common download file type, has potential risk.

Can you give me some clues?

Thanks

Comment: Might be because you have to sign the MSI with a certificate in order to be fully accepted, not sure though, IE is very picky. One place to get signing certificates for free is http://www.cacert.org/ to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @MichaelOverhorst You should make it the answer. You have to sign the package so that it becomes trusted. Unfortunately, the Certification Authority root of the cacert.org is not trusted either, so you have to buy code signing certificate from VeriSign or Thawte if you want you package to be trusted.

Comment: Great to see you have figured it out, i thought the ones from cacert.org would do the trick, but also i remember an alternative that required adding it to the local trusted root certificates for testing purposes, that way it would look like it was trusted on that specific machine and you could see if that solved it. Thanks for the feedback and feel free to edit the answer if you have additional information that could be useful for the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bundle what we know now and create a answer:
This problem occurs because the application is not trusted, in order to make it trusted it has to be signed with a code signing certificate. This ensures the end-user that your application  is not altered in any way and should be safe to execute. Code signing certificates can be bought at multiple places such as:

http://www.instantssl.com

http://www.verisign.com

http://www.thawte.com

https://www.globalsign.com

In addition to that, you could generate a certificate yourself which after adding it to the local Trusted Root Certificate's should act like it is trusted, please note that this is only for testing purposes and does not make it trusted on any other computer.

Answer (score 0):

Signing an MSI is always a good idea, as the UAC prompt for an unsigned MSI is different than for one with a valid digital signature.

For more information on how to do this, refer to MSDN - [How to: Sign Setup Files with SignTool.exe (Windows Installer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee290833.aspx)

If you want a certificate trusted by standard Windows PCs you will need a **Microsoft Authenticode Code Signing Certificate** signed by a trusted third party, personally I use Comodo - http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/